# What easy algorithms are there for calculating products of cycle decompositions?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-programming

Here is the easy algorithm we are taught for adding two numbers in base-10 notation. We are taught this algorithm in first or second grade.

```
  sub infix:<+>(@x, @y) {
   #x, y are lists of digits
   #returns a list of digits
   my @greater = (@y.elems > @x.elems) ?? @y !! @x;
   my @lesser_ = (@y.elems > @x.elems) ?? @x !! @y;
   my @gPopped = @greater;
   my @lPopped = @lesser_;
   my $carry = 0;
   my @sum;
   loop (my $i = 0; $i < @greater.elems; $i++) {
     if (@lPopped.elems >= 1) {
       my $gDigit = @gPopped.tail;
       my $lDigit = @lPopped.tail;
       @sum.append: (($gDigit + $lDigit) % 10) + $carry;
       $carry = (($gDigit + $lDigit) / 10).floor;
       @lPopped = @lPopped.head(@lPopped.elems - 1);
       @gPopped = @gPopped.head(@gPopped.elems - 1);
     } else {
        my $gDigit = @gPopped.tail;
        @sum.append: $gDigit + $carry;
        $carry = 0;
        @gPopped = @gPopped.head(@gPopped.elems - 1);
     }
   }
   return @sum.reverse;
  }
```

The algorithm is very easy and a child can do it by hand. Meanwhile, I am unaware of any algorithm for multiplying two permutations decomposed into cycle form (e.g. $(123)\times(12)(34)$). What is an easy algorithm for multiplying two cycles?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it manually, taking the example of $(123) \cdot (12)(34)$.

Start with a number appearing on the right permutation, say 1. The right permutation sends it to 2, and the left to 3.

Doing the same with 3, we get 4 and then 4.

Doing the same with 4, we get 3 then 1. We have closed a cycle $(134)$.

Now take another number on the right (or left) permutation not already covered – has to be 2. It gets sent to 1 then 2. We have closed a cycle – 2 is a fixed point.

In total, the result is $(134)$.

Now let's compute $(12)(34) \cdot (123)$.

Let's start with 1. It goes to 2 then 1. So it's a fixed point.

Let's try 2 next. It goes to 3 then 4, which goes to itself then 3, which goes to 1 then 2. We have closed a cycle $(243)$. That's the answer.